# Normal Subgroups and Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to prove the following using Lagrange's Theorem:

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that if $x \in G$ and $\text{gcd}(|x|,|G:N|)=1$, then $x \in N$.

I know that $|N|$ divides $|G|$ and that $|x|$ divides $|G|$, but I am getting stuck trying to put these facts together. I am also having trouble understanding the significance of the gcd of $|x|$ and $|G:N|$ being 1.

Comment: Consider the order of the element $\pi(x) \in G/N$ where $\pi : G\to G/N$ denotes the quotient map.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the canonical homomorphism $\pi\colon G\rightarrow G/N$, see the comment.
Since $x^n=e$ implies $\pi(x)^n=[e]$ for a homomorphism $\pi$, the order of $\pi(x)$ divides the order of $x$, which is coprime to $|G/N|$ by assumption. Hence $|\pi(x)|=1$, which means $\pi(x)=[e]$, so that $x\in N$.

Comment: How does $x^n=e$ imply $\pi(x)^n=[e]$?

Comment: $[e]=\pi(e)=\pi(x^n)=\pi(x)^n$.